# Retrieve a list of child entities for parent classes that match variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been working on an XML parsing system using Entity Framework and LINQ and I am now having some problems in translating previous SQL queries where the table was not in a normalised format.

I have the following structure:

```
1. Message                     (Each message type has one to many messagetype341s)
2. MessageType341              (Each messagetype341 has 1 to many meters)       
3. Meter                       (Each meter has 2 channel informations)
4. ChannelInformation          (Each channel information has 48 interval informations)
5. Interval Information
```

The **ReadDate** and **CustomerNo** are in the MessageType341 level. I am trying to write sequel where I put in the the CustomerNo and the ReadDate as variables and then based on the return of the messagetype341s listed in then retrieves the subsquent meter, channel information and interval information for the related messagetype341s

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT c.SerialNumber,
       b.ReadDate,
       d.RegisterTypeCode,
       e.IntervalStatusCode,
       d.UOM_Code,
       e.IntervalPeriodTimestamp,
       e.IntervalValue
FROM   MarketMessage AS a,
       MessageType341 AS b,
       Meter AS c,
       ChannelInformation AS d,
       IntervalInformation AS e
WHERE  b.CustomerNo = '12348750528'
       AND b.ReadDate >= '01 nov 2014'
       AND b.ReadDate <= '30 nov 2014'
ORDER  BY b.ReadDate
```

But it does not seem to be returning values that are matching my expected values, am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: In what way are the results not what you expected?  Too many rows? Too few? Unrelated records?  A couple of have guessed at your issue but a better explanation of what's not working would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you need to use LEFT jons.

```
select c.SerialNumber, b.ReadDate, d.RegisterTypeCode, e.IntervalStatusCode, d.UOM_Code,   e.IntervalPeriodTimestamp, e.IntervalValue
from MarketMessage as a LEFT JOIN MessageType341 as b ON a.PK = b.FK
LEFT JOIN  Meter as c ON b.PK = c.FK
LEFT JOIN  ChannelInformation as d ON c.PK = d.FK
LEFT JOIN  IntervalInformation as e ON d.PK = e.FK
where b.CustomerNo = '12348750528'
and b.ReadDate BETWEEN '01 nov 2014' AND and b.ReadDate <= '30 nov 2014'
order by b.ReadDate
```

Where:

**PK** = Primary Key

**FK** = Foreign Key

The difference between each type of join, please see: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: This worked after I updated the IntervalInformation on condition which should have been d.FK = e.PK

Answer (score 1):

You are using old `JOIN` syntax, and not filtering those results:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1,Table2
```

Returns every row from `Table1` paired with every row from `Table2`, a `CROSS JOIN` or cartesian product.

You could filter results based on a relationship ie: `WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.Parent_ID`, but it's better to use standard `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT c.SerialNumber, b.ReadDate, d.RegisterTypeCode, e.IntervalStatusCode, d.UOM_Code,   e.IntervalPeriodTimestamp, e.IntervalValue
FROM MarketMessage as a
JOIN MessageType341 as b
  ON a.ID = b.Parent_ID
JOIN Meter as c
  ON b.ID = c.Parent_ID
JOIN ChannelInformation as d
  ON c.ID = d.Parent_ID
JOIN IntervalInformation as e
  ON d.ID = e.Parent_ID
WHERE b.CustomerNo = '12348750528'
  AND b.ReadDate >= '01 nov 2014'
  AND b.ReadDate <= '30 nov 2014'
ORDER BY b.ReadDate
```

If you have some records that don't have children you can change to `LEFT JOIN` to bring back all records regardless of whether they have every level of information.

Comment: Thank you also for this but as you have mentioned probably better to use the joins so although I could not mark it as correct I have upvoted your answer thank you